# Google doesn't show my location

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I'd like to get a marker with my correct position on the map. In the information from the marker should be the address. I think I did mix something up or forget something, because with my code the map doesn't show me my location.. can you help me?

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
     GoogleMap map;
     MarkerOptions mp;
    public Address location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
         .getMap();

       }


     private class ReverseGeocodingTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, String>{
            Context mContext;

            public ReverseGeocodingTask(Context context){
                super();
                mContext = context;
            }

            // Finding address using reverse geocoding
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext);
                double latitude = params[0].latitude;
                double longitude = params[0].longitude;

                List<Address> addresses = null;
                String addressText="";

                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude,1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0 ){
                    Address address = addresses.get(0);

                    addressText = String.format("%s, %s, %s",
                    address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                    address.getLocality(),
                    address.getCountryName());
                }

                return addressText;

            }


    @Override
      public void onPostExecute(String addressText) {

        map.clear();


        mp.title(addressText);


        mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

        map.addMarker(mp);


        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
         new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16));

       }



    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
           double lat = location.getLatitude();
           double lon = location.getLongitude();
           LatLng point = new LatLng(lat, lon);
           new ReverseGeocodingTask().execute(point);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }}
```

Here is the new logcat..

```
 08-08 11:51:19.521: E/dalvikvm(23602): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
    08-08 11:51:19.521: E/dalvikvm(23602): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
    08-08 11:51:19.521: E/dalvikvm(23602): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
    08-08 11:51:19.671: E/dalvikvm(23602): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method gls.a
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602): Process: ch.swisscom.manuel, PID: 23602
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602):    at android.location.GeocoderParams.<init>(GeocoderParams.java:50)
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602):    at android.location.Geocoder.<init>(Geocoder.java:83)
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602):    at android.location.Geocoder.<init>(Geocoder.java:95)
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602):    at ch.swisscom.manuel.MainActivity$ReverseGeocodingTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:55)
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602):    at ch.swisscom.manuel.MainActivity$ReverseGeocodingTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    08-08 11:51:24.886: E/AndroidRuntime(23602):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: What is your location??? need to add marker in `onLocationChnaged(.....)` method and try

Comment: You already put it on your main acitivity..

Comment: And where should i place the onLocationChanged methode? In an other project i did it like that 

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        map.clear();

        MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();

        mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

        mp.title("my position");

        map.addMarker(mp);

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works. I would like to post the correct code for the people with the same problem.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);


    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
}

private class ReverseGeocodingTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
        double latitude = params[0].latitude;
        double longitude = params[0].longitude;

        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String addressText = null;
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);

             addressText= String.format(
                    "%s, %s, %s",
                    address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address
                            .getAddressLine(0) : "", address.getLocality(),
                    address.getCountryName());
        }

        final MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();

        final LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        mp.position(userLocation);
        mp.title(addressText);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Marker marker = map.addMarker(mp);
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation,
                        16));       
                marker.showInfoWindow();
            }
        });

        return addressText;
    }

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
            location.getLongitude());
    ReverseGeocodingTask rgt = new ReverseGeocodingTask();

    rgt.execute(userLocation);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere a function call to ReverseGeocodingTask class

call it when ever location is changed that is in onLocationChanged

change onLocationChanged method as follows

```
 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lon = location.getLongitude();
            LatLng point = new LatLng(lat, lon);
            new ReverseGeocodingTask().execute(point);

    }
```

Hope this works...cheers !!

Comment: try changing mcontext to this

Comment: getfromlocation may return null if there is no backend service.This may be solved by rebooting in most cases

Comment: does anyone have another idea?

Comment: well what was the statement at line 55 in your code ?

Comment: sorry sir I can't follow your. Android is a new area for me. Line 55 is Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this); resp. Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext);

Comment: add this after setContentView in mainactivity class ReverseGeocodingTask rgt=new ReverseGeocodingTask(this); and remove super(); in constructor